# redirected you too many times

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, https, ubuntu-14.04

I have a ubuntu vps and i have setup a wordpress installation on it. Also i have a domains whose nameserver is set to cloudflare's nameserver, all the dns setting are on cloudflare and i also have TLS certificate for domain. And i have installed certificates on my server. I have written redirect command `Redirect permanent / https://example.com/` in unsecured virtual host i.e port 80. When i try to access the website it throws an error `example.com redirected you too many times.`

The virtual host on 80 is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and virtual host on port 443 is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@example.com
                ServerName example.com:443
                ServerAlias www.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

               SSLEngine on

               SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem
               SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key

               <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>

                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Please could anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirect loop is typically caused by one or more of:

- a `.htaccess` file on your HTPS site that does another redirect back to port 80
- a Wordpress install that is still configured as `http://www.example.com` in [`wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)
- a Reverse Proxy is used (e.g. CloudFlare) that is configured (by design or mistakenly) for SSL off loading and forwards HTTPS requests over plain http to your Wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn got it resolved. Actually there was a [link](.htaccess) file in the outside the root wordpress directory, i deleted it and it got resolved.